# Animação em imagens

Tags: java, android

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que uma imagem gire por exemplo em 90 graus quando clicado nela? Quero que ao clicar na imagem, ela dê uma volta, como um ponteiro de relógio por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas `animate().rotation(angle).start()` dentro do método `setOnClickListener` do seu botão já resolveria o problema. Sendo assim, basta definir um valor para a variável `angle`, que seria referente ao angulo desejado. Veja:

```
int angle = 90;
imageView.animate().rotation(angle).start();
```

Comment: Perfeito valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método [View##SetRotation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)) do próprio componente **ImageView**.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                  
        imageView.setRotation(90);
    }
});
```

O 90 pode ser qualquer valor, e se caso você quiser adicionar uma rotação, ou seja, pegar a rotação atual da view e aplicar mais um valor, apenas pegue a rotação com **getRotation** e adicione o seu valor.

```
imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() + valor);
```

Se a rotação dela for 90, a nova rotação será 180 e assim por diante.

**Obs**: Como o autor do post disse, esse método apenas aplica uma rotação na imagem, ela não faz com que haja uma animação na mesma.

---

Para rotacionar a imagem com uma animação, você pode utilizar o [LinearInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LinearInterpolator.html)

```
imageView.animate().rotationBy(90).setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
```

**Onde**:

- rotationBy(): é a rotação de destino da view, ou com qual rotação ela vai ficar no fim da duração.
- setDuration(): como o próprio nome diz, é a duração que a rotação terá.
- setInterpolator(): é, basicamente, como a animação  se comportará.

Você pode utilizar outros atributos, como o `withStartAction`, como próprio nome diz, quando a animação começar, ele te permite aplicar uma ação na view, por exemplo, aplicar uma animação em outra view ou nela mesma.

```
imageView.animate().rotationBy(90).withStartAction(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       imageView.setRotation(90);
    }
}).setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Comment: Dessa forma a imagem irá apenas girar, sem nenhuma animação.

Comment: Ah, vdd, vou adicionar mais alguma coisa. Eu entendi errado. :D

Comment: @IAMLuc porém assim não tem animação que é o que está pedindo na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado! Editei a pergunta! :)

Answer (score 1):

### 1ª solução (simples)

No método `onClick` da sua imagem, adicione o seguinte código:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageView.animate().rotation(90).start();
    }
});
```

### 2ª solução (mais opções)

Crie o arquivo `button_rotate.xml` na pasta `anim` dentro do seu projeto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/animation"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="90" />
```

Agora crie a animação na sua classe Java, mais precisamente, dentro do método `onClick` da sua imagem:

```
/* Pega a sua ImageView*/
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);

/* Cria a animação */
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.animation);
rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

/* Inicia a animação */
iv.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Para parar a animação:

```
iv.clearAnimation();
```

*Traduzido e adaptado de: [Rotate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016126/when-click-a-button-rotate-image-clockwise-in-android/18016331#18016331)*